# React js, axios - multiple request

Tags: reactjs

Today when using axios and getting data from .get, axios started sending multiple requests, not just one. I have no idea why this problem occurred, I cannot solve it. Below I will post all the necessary functions that handle the request and display of component components. Below I have included the code where axios executes the request and the function that sets the state of allVotes with the previously retrieved length array.

There are several responses from api per second in console.log and after some time an error 423 appears that the request limit has been exceeded.

````
import React from "react";
import { BiUser } from "react-icons/bi"
import ProgressBar from "@ramonak/react-progress-bar";
import axios from "axios";

export class MainPage extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
            this.state = {
                raceName: "",
                date: new Date().getFullYear(),
                userVoted: 'false',
                firstDriverVotes: 0,
                secondDriverVotes: 0,
                allVotes: 0,
                firstVoteDriver: '',
                firstDriverNumber: 0,
                firstDriverDateOfBirth: '',
                firstVoteSecondDriver: '',
                firstVoteSecondDriverDateOfBirth: '',
                firstVoteSecondDriverNumber: 0,
                raceRound: 0,
                standings: [],
                actualRaceResults: false,
                actualRaceStandings: [],
                noActualRaceResults: true,
                sesssionEnded: false,
        }
        this.submitVote = this.submitVote.bind(this);
        this.votesStateSet = this.votesStateSet.bind(this);
    }

    requestOption = {
        method: "GET",
        redirect: 'follow'
    };

    componentDidMount(){
        const date = new Date();
        const year = date.getFullYear();
        const dayName = date.toLocaleDateString('pl-PL', {weekday: 'long'});
        let newDate = date.toISOString().slice(0,10)
        //let newDate = '2022-09-11'
        //const dayName = 'niedziela'
        this.fetchOption(year,newDate, dayName)
    }

    fetchOption(data, date1, dayName){
        const activitesF1 = [
            {
              FirstPractice: 'piątek',
              SecondPractice: 'piątek',
              ThirdPractice: 'sobota',
              Qualifying: 'sobota',
              Race: 'niedziela'
            }
        ]
        fetch(`https://ergast.com/api/f1/current.json`, this.requestOption)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => {
            const data_races = [result]
            data_races.forEach(element => {
                const races = [element.MRData.RaceTable.Races]
                for (let i = 0; i < races.length; i++){
                    for(let j = 0; j < races[i].length; j++){
                        if(activitesF1[0].FirstPractice === dayName){
                            if(races[i][j].FirstPractice.date === date1){
                                const data = races[i][j]
                                this.displayData(data)
                            }
                        }else if(activitesF1[0].Qualifying === dayName){
                            if(races[i][j].Qualifying.date === date1){
                                const data = races[i][j]
                                this.displayData(data)
                                
                            }
                        }else if(activitesF1[0].Race === dayName){
                            if(races[i][j].date === date1){
                                const data = races[i][j]
                                this.displayData(data)
                        }
                    }else{
                        window.location.replace('/noraceday')
                    }
            }
        }
        })
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error))
    }


    votesStateSet(state){
        if(state > 0){
            this.setState({
                allVotes: state,
            })
        }else if(state === 'true'){
            console.log(state)
            this.setState({
                userVoted: state,
            })
        }
    }




    submitVote(driver){
      if(driver === this.state.firstVoteDriver){
        axios
        .post("https://6339bfb9383946bc7ff8296d.mockapi.io/voting",{
            driverA: true
        })
      }else if(driver === this.state.firstVoteSecondDriver){
        axios
          .post("https://6339bfb9383946bc7ff8296d.mockapi.io/voting",{
            driverB: true
        })
    }
    this.votesStateSet('true')
}


    displayData(data){
        this.setState({
            raceName: data.raceName,
            firstVoteDriver: 'Max Verstappen',
            firstDriverNumber: '1',
            firstDriverDateOfBirth: '30/09/1997',
            firstVoteSecondDriver: 'Charles Lecrlec',
            firstVoteSecondDriverNumber: '16',
            firstVoteSecondDriverDateOfBirth: '16/10/1997',
            raceRound: data.round,
        })
        this.fetchStanding(data.round)
    }

    fetchStanding(round){
        const date = new Date();
        const year = date.getFullYear();
        fetch(`https://ergast.com/api/f1/${year}/driverStandings.json`)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then(result => {
            const result1 = result.MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsLists[0].DriverStandings 
            this.setState({
                standings: result1,
            })
        })
        fetch(`https://ergast.com/api/f1/${year}/${round}/results.json`)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then(result => {
            const result2 = result.MRData.RaceTable.Races[0].Results
            if(result2.length > 0){
                this.setState({
                    actualRaceResults: true,
                    actualRaceStandings: result2,
                    sesssionEnded: true,
                })
            }else{
                return;
            }
        })

    }


      renderResults(){
              const firstDriverVotes = this.state.firstVoteDriver
              const secondDriverVotes = this.state.firstVoteSecondDriver
              const allVotes = this.state.allVotes
              axios.get('https://6339bfb9383946bc7ff8296d.mockapi.io/voting').then(
                    (res) => {
                        console.log(res.data)
                        const results = res.data
                        const results_length = results.length
                        this.votesStateSet(results_length)
                    },
                    (err) => {
                        console.log(err)
                    }
                    )
                    return(
                        <>
                        <div className="first-vote-container">
                            <h1 className="container-title" style={{fontFamily: 'F1-Regular', textAlign: 'center'}}>Actual results of poll {this.state.date} {this.state.raceName}</h1>
                        <div className="results-container">
                            <div className="results-first-driver">
                                 <img className="image-driver-results" src="https://www.formula1.com/content/fom-website/en/drivers/max-verstappen/jcr:content/image.img.1920.medium.jpg/1646819045507.jpg" alt={this.state.firstVoteDriver}/>
                                 <h3 className="first-driver-name" style={{fontFamily: 'F1-Regular', marginTop: '60px', marginLeft:'10px'}}>Driver name: {this.state.firstVoteDriver}</h3>
                            <ProgressBar 
                               className="progress-bar-first"
                               completed={firstDriverVotes}
                               height="30px"
                               width="300px"
                               bgColor="#E10600"
                               fontFamily='F1-Regular'
                               labelAlignment="outside"
                               labelColor="#000"
                               maxCompleted={allVotes}
                               customLabel={`${firstDriverVotes} votes for this driver / ${allVotes} all votes `}
                               />
                            </div>
                            <div className="results-second-driver">
                                 <img className="image-driver-results" src="https://www.formula1.com/content/fom-website/en/drivers/charles-leclerc/jcr:content/image.img.1920.medium.jpg/1646818893219.jpg" alt={this.state.firstVoteSecondDriver}/>
                                 <h3 className="second-driver-name" style={{fontFamily: 'F1-Regular', marginTop: '-140px', marginLeft:'220px'}}>Driver name: {this.state.firstVoteSecondDriver}</h3>
                            <ProgressBar 
                               className="progress-bar-second"
                               completed={secondDriverVotes}
                               height="30px"
                               width="300px"
                               bgColor="#E10600"
                               fontFamily='F1-Regular'
                               labelAlignment="outside"
                               labelColor="#000"
                               maxCompleted={allVotes}
                               customLabel={`${secondDriverVotes} votes for this driver / ${allVotes} all votes `}
                               />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div> 
                        </>
                    )
        }
    render(){
        const standingsLists = this.state.standings
        const voted = this.state.userVoted
        const sessionEnded = this.state.sesssionEnded
        const renderRaceResults = () => {
            const acutalRaceStand = this.state.actualRaceStandings
            return (
                <div className="first-vote-container">
                    <h1 className="container-title" style={{fontFamily: 'F1-Regular', textAlign: 'center'}}>Results of {this.state.date} {this.state.raceName}</h1>
                    <div className="results-container">
                        <ul className="standings-list">
                        {acutalRaceStand.map(item => (
                                <li key={item.position} style={{fontFamily: 'F1-Regular'}}>Finishing position: {item.position}, Driver: {item.Driver.givenName} {item.Driver.familyName}, Laps: {item.laps}, Points: {item.points}, Status: {item.status}</li>
                            ))}
                        </ul>

                    </div>
                </div>

            )

        }
        return(
             <>
               <div className="header">
                <h1 className="page-title" style={{fontFamily: 'F1-Regular'}}>F1 Vote for Winner -</h1>
                <p className="actual-grandprix" style={{fontFamily: 'F1-Regular'}}>{this.state.date} {this.state.raceName}</p>
                <button className="sign-in-admin" style={{fontFamily: 'F1-Button'}}><BiUser style={{position: 'relative', top: '2px'}}/> Sign In</button>
               </div>
               <div className='content-container'>
                <div className="container-standing">
                    <h1 className="standings" style={{fontFamily: 'F1-Regular', textAlign: 'center'}}>Standings after round {this.state.raceRound}/22</h1>
                    <div className='standings-content'>
                        <ul className="standings-list">
                        {standingsLists.map(item => (
                                <li key={item.position} style={{fontFamily: 'F1-Regular'}}>Position: {item.position}, Driver: {item.Driver.givenName} {item.Driver.familyName}, Points: {item.points}, Constructor: {item.Constructors[0].name}</li>
                            ))}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
               {voted === 'false' && sessionEnded === false &&
                 <div className='first-vote-container'>
                    <h1 className="container-title" style={{fontFamily: 'F1-Regular', textAlign: 'center'}}>Who will win {this.state.date} {this.state.raceName}?</h1>
                    <div className="first-driver-container">
                          <img className="image-driver" src="https://www.formula1.com/content/fom-website/en/drivers/max-verstappen/jcr:content/image.img.1920.medium.jpg/1646819045507.jpg" alt={this.state.firstVoteDriver} onClick={() => this.submitVote(this.state.firstVoteDriver)}/>
                       <div className="first-driver-info-content">
                          <h3 className="first-driver-name" style={{fontFamily: 'F1-Regular', marginLeft: '20px' }}>Driver name: {this.state.firstVoteDriver}</h3>
                          <h3 className="first-driver-number" style={{fontFamily: 'F1-Regular', marginLeft: '20px' }}>Driver number: {this.state.firstDriverNumber}</h3>
                          <h3 className="first-driver-birth" style={{fontFamily: 'F1-Regular', marginLeft: '20px' }}>Driver date of birth: {this.state.firstDriverDateOfBirth}</h3>
                       </div>
                    </div> 
                    <div className="second-driver-container">
                        <img className="image-driver" src="https://www.formula1.com/content/fom-website/en/drivers/charles-leclerc/jcr:content/image.img.1920.medium.jpg/1646818893219.jpg" alt={this.state.firstVoteSecondDriver} onClick={() => this.submitVote(this.state.firstVoteSecondDriver)}/>            
                    <div className="second-driver-info-content">
                        <h3 className="second-driver-name" style={{fontFamily: 'F1-Regular', marginLeft: '20px' }}>Driver name: {this.state.firstVoteSecondDriver}</h3>   
                        <h3 className="second-driver-name" style={{fontFamily: 'F1-Regular', marginLeft: '20px' }}>Driver number: {this.state.firstVoteSecondDriverNumber}</h3>   
                        <h3 className="second-driver-name" style={{fontFamily: 'F1-Regular', marginLeft: '20px' }}>Driver date of birth: {this.state.firstVoteSecondDriverDateOfBirth}</h3>   
                    </div>   
                    </div>  
                    </div> 
                  }{voted === 'true' &&
                    this.renderResults()
                  }{sessionEnded === true &&
                    renderRaceResults()
                  }
               </div>
               
             </>
        )
}
}```
````

Comment: Can you post the full example? It looks like the axios.get will be called on every render, and it triggers a setState which will cause another render resulting in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just moved out axios.get function outside of function which is rendered. Now it works perfectly.